# Implementing a recurring relationship

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the expression y = (1 + 4 + 7 + ... + 301) / (2 + 5 + 8 + ... + 272) by a recursive function, but what I wrote doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm not doing right?
This version returns the error >Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

here is my code

```
int calcSum(int start, int end, int steep){
    if(start == 0){
        return 0;
    } else{
        return start + calcSum(start,end,steep);
    }
}
int main() {

    printf("y = %d", calcSum(1,301,3)/ calcSum(1,272,3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never actually use the `steep` value in the calculations.

Comment: How do you expect the end condition `if(start == 0)` ever to become true considering every recursive call has the same `start` value?

Comment: @kaylum I'm sorry, I'm a little confused.

Comment: What is your expected output? `1`?

Comment: @mch idk, I'm waiting for the result of the expression, I don't know if it's 1 or not

Comment: You can easily figure out the result by using arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @RinkeshP recursive? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your recursive call, you are not doing anything to make sure the function stops calling and hence it breaks. When you say you want to add numbers recursively, there are 3 things you need to do: call the same function(obviously), have a termination condition and in this case actually pass the values such that in each call it adds as per the sequence needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calcSum(int start, int end, int steep){
 // Stop calling once you have added all numbers
        if(start<=end){
            return start + calcSum(start+steep,end,steep); // increment start with steep so that in each call the next term in the sequence is added.
        }
        else return 0; //return 0 after start > end as we don't need to add after that.
}
int main(void) {
    printf("y = %d", calcSum(1,301,3)/ calcSum(2,272,3));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the working code would look like.